# Get day number of month from UTC format

Tags: javascript, datetime

I would get day number from UTC date format.

```js
var a = new Date("2018-10-27T22:10:00.780Z");
        var r = a.getDate();
        document.getElementById("myId").innerHTML = r;
```

```html
<p id="myId">
</p>
```

my problem is when I put `2018-10-27T22:10:00.780Z` or before that date , the result is always shifted and when I put > `2018-10-27T22:10:00.780Z` I get the right date.

What I expect is to get right day number of month

Comment: try `getUTCDate()` will get the exact result

Comment: `getDate()` work with respect to your local time zone on your machine (see docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate ), and since I'm in Europe I'm getting +2, which rolls it over to the 28th. Try @ChintuYadavSara 's suggestion

Comment: Your example dates seem identical to me. Otherwise it is your timezone, remember that being in a "+1:00" time zone, but in summer time ends up being +2:00. And 22:10 + 2:00 is 0:10 the next day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `a.getDate()` with `a.getUTCDate()`.

```js
var a = new Date("2018-10-27T22:10:00.780Z");
var r = a.getUTCDate();

console.log(r);
```